# quicksort going out of bound

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, quicksort

I know that there are other question about this, but nobody has my implementation of quicksort so I need your help to fix this.

Here is my quicksort:

```
    //u is first index (0) and v is last (numberOfPatients - 1)
public void quickSort(Patient arrayPatients[], int u, int v) { 
    int q;

    if(u == v) return;  
    q = perno(arrayPatients, u, v);

    if(u < q) quickSort(arrayPatients, u, q-1); 
    if(q < v) quickSort(arrayPatients, q+1, v);
}


public int perno(Patient arrayPatients[], int first, int last){
    Patient temp = new Patient();
    int i = first;
    int j = last + 1;
    long pivot = arrayPatients[first].priority;

    while(i < j){
        do i++;
        while(arrayPatients[i].priority <= pivot && i<= last);  //Line 1441
        do j--; 
        while(arrayPatients[j].priority > pivot && j >= first);
        if(i < j){  
            //Swap arrayPatients[i] and arrayPatients[j]
            temp = arrayPatients[i];
            arrayPatients[i] = arrayPatients[j];
            arrayPatients[j] = temp;
        }
    }
    //Swap arrayPatients[first] and arrayPatients[j]
    temp = arrayPatients[first];
    arrayPatients[first] = arrayPatients[j];
    arrayPatients[j] = temp;
    return j;
}
```

edit:
I have 4 patients, this is the error I get:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at sorter.Sort.perno(Sort.java:1441)
    at sorter.Sort.quickSort(Sort.java:1425)
    at sorter.Sort.quickSort(Sort.java:1428)
    at sorter.Sort.sorting(Sort.java:851)
    at sorter.Home$27.run(Home.java:1314)
```

I've added a comment with the number of the incriminated line

Comment: Could you post the full error message?

Comment: Sure wait a second

Comment: edited with the error

Comment: At line 1441 arrayPatients[i] at some point i is an index that does not exist. Try putting "System.out.println("Index: " + i);" inside that while loop and see what i gets set to when it errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most likely due to checking array at index first, then checking if the index is within bounds at all.

Instead:

```
    do i++;
    while(arrayPatients[i].priority <= pivot && i<= last);  //Line 1441
    do j--; 
    while(arrayPatients[j].priority > pivot && j >= first);
```

Try:

```
    do i++;
    while(i<= last && arrayPatients[i].priority <= pivot);  //Line 1441
    do j--; 
    while(j >= first && arrayPatients[j].priority > pivot);
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: Man really, Thanks!! you made my day! It was so easy that I didn't thought at all. Thank you!

Comment: Also, why aren't you using Arrays.sort( T[] array, Comparator<T> comparator)? The comparator you need would look like this: comparator: (o1,o2)->Long.compare( o1.priority, o2.priority ) or simply Comparator.comparingLong( Patient::getPriority ). I don't see in your code much difference from standard quicksort (which has some nasty O(n^2) worst case) and you will almost definitely see speed up by using java's default implementation.

Comment: Quick sort is the best solution in my case because I have a big number of elements in my arrays and I know that them are always random. Quicksort has O(n^2) only if elements are already sorted and this is not my case

Comment: Java has definitely well optimised sorting and I doubt standard quicksort can compare to it. I'm also pretty much sure it uses insertion sort on small arrays (around 15 elements) to further squeeze the performance. I will make some quick tests to see if the performance difference is better in your case since you have the cost of having to maintain your own sorting.

Comment: Well that is quite interesting. I ran some tests on various sizes and it seems the standard java algorithm for sorting an array is around twice as slow. Well I'm kinda disappointed in Oracle.